# Is there a default license for Firefox add-ons?

Tags: firefox, licensing, firefox-addon

Do they have to be GPL or can they be something else? And if nothing is specified in the code are they considered to be GPL by default?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not a lawyer, so take this with a grain of salt.

First off, Mozilla has nothing to do this. There is no reason to believe that Firefox add-ons are [GPL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html)-licensed by default. That's because the license of the browser doesn't affect the license of the add-ons; they don't typically reuse the browser's source code. (In fact, Firefox itself isn't necessarily GPL'd. Mozilla releases it under a [tri-license](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/) which includes the [Mozilla Public License](http://www.mozilla.org/MPL/MPL-1.1.html) as one of the license options.)

So, I'd imagine that if you don't specify a license to an add-on, then that add-on defaults to whatever copyright control would be extended to you as author of the add-on, depending on your jurisdiction.

Now if you used GPL'd code in your add-on, then that add-on would obviously be GPL-licensed if you released it publicly. Unless you got special permission from the original author to use a different license, of course.

Comment: "Not even Firefox is GPL'd. It is released under the Mozilla Public License."  -- GPL/LGPL/MPL tri-license actually, but everything else you say is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Nickolay. I've updated my answer to mention the tri-license. I was digressing, anyway.